# Resign First Responder function in SKScene

Tags: xcode, sprite-kit, uitextfield

I am trying to create a game that requires to create a textfield in SKScene. I have built the text field successfully, but bringing the keyboard down is the problem. This is my code so far.

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
var sceneFrame : CGRect = CGRect()
var textFieldFrame : CGRect = CGRect()
var textField : UITextField = UITextField()
var skView: SKView = SKView()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    sceneFrame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
    let scene = SKScene(size: sceneFrame.size)
    scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    textFieldFrame = CGRect(origin: .init(x: 100, y: 200), size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 30))
    textField = UITextField(frame: textFieldFrame)
    textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    textField.placeholder = "Phone Number"
    textField.keyboardType = .numberPad
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    self.view!.addSubview(textField)
    self.view!.presentScene(scene)
    // Where to put the textField.resignFirstResponder() ?
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered

}
}
```

Any answers would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are not adding:

```
textfield.delegate = self
```

Then you could call the function:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {   

    // Hides the keyboard  

    textField.resignFirstResponder()  
    return true  
}
```

Declaring the delegate statement initiate the function textFieldShouldReturn.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Dont forget to mention declaring the class conforms to the delegate

Comment: Thank you! I will add that.